# How to use z3 split clauses of unsat cores & try to find out unsat core again

Tags: c++, split, z3, seek

Could you like to tell how to split clauses of unsat cores?
And here is question 2 regarding after found out unsat cores, I will try to seek again.
Would you like to tell how to do this?

Thank you very much.

---

How to split the clauses as below

```
`and` (`or` (`<=_int` 1002 x1) (`<=_int` 1000 x1)) (`and` (`or` (`<=_int` 0 (`+_int` x2 (`*_int` -1003 x1))) (`<=_int` 0 (`+_int` x2 (`*_int` -1230 x1)))) (`and` (`or` (`<=_int` 0 (`+_int` x3 (`*_int` -1999 x2)))
```

Regarding to the question 2,

```
cout<<s.check(3,assumptions)<<endl;
    expr_vector core = s.unsat_core();
................

expr assumptions2[2] = {p1,p3};
                    cout<<"check next"<<s.check(2,assumptions2)<<endl;
                    expr_vector core1 = s.unsat_core();
                    for(unsigned int k=0;k<core1.size();++k){
                            cout<<"New core size "<<k<<endl;
                            cout<<"New unsat core "<<core1[k]<<endl;
                    }
```

calling the unsat core function again, it cannot give the unsat cores again.
Thank you very much.

Comment: I didn't understand the question. Could you give an example of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if I understood your question. It seems you have an assertion of the form `(and c1 (and c2 c3))`, and you want to track `c1`, `c2` and `c3` individually.

In Z3, we use answer literals to track assertions. An answer literal is essentially a fresh Boolean that is used to track an assertion. That is, whether the assertion was used (by Z3) to show unsatisfiability of the whole set of assertions or not. For example, if we want to track assertion `F`, we create a fresh Boolean variable `p` and assert `p implies F`. Then, we provide `p` as an argument for the check method.

If `F` is a big conjunction and we want to track its elements individually, we should extract its elements and create an answer literal for each one of them. Here is the complete example that does the trick. You can test it by including it in the `example.cpp` file that is included in the Z3 distribution. Note that you have to include `#include<vector>`.

```
/**
   \brief Unsat core example 2
*/
void unsat_core_example2() {
    std::cout << "unsat core example 2\n";
    context c;
    // The answer literal mechanism, described in the previous example,
    // tracks assertions. An assertion can be a complicated
    // formula containing containing the conjunction of many subformulas.
    expr p1 = c.bool_const("p1");
    expr x  = c.int_const("x");
    expr y  = c.int_const("y");
    solver s(c);
    expr F  = x > 10 && y > x && y < 5 && y > 0;
    s.add(implies(p1, F));
    expr assumptions[1] = { p1 };
    std::cout << s.check(1, assumptions) << "\n";
    expr_vector core = s.unsat_core();
    std::cout << core << "\n";
    std::cout << "size: " << core.size() << "\n";
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < core.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << core[i] << "\n";
    }
    // The core is not very informative, since p1 is tracking the formula F
    // that is a conjunction of subformulas.
    // Now, we use the following piece of code to break this conjunction
    // into individual subformulas. First, we flat the conjunctions by
    // using the method simplify.
    std::vector<expr> qs; // auxiliary vector used to store new answer literals.
    assert(F.is_app()); // I'm assuming F is an application.
    if (F.decl().decl_kind() == Z3_OP_AND) {
        // F is a conjunction
        std::cout << "F num. args (before simplify): " << F.num_args() << "\n";
        F = F.simplify();
        std::cout << "F num. args (after simplify):  " << F.num_args() << "\n";
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < F.num_args(); i++) {
            std::cout << "Creating answer literal q" << i << " for " << F.arg(i) << "\n";
            std::stringstream qname; qname << "q" << i;
            expr qi = c.bool_const(qname.str().c_str()); // create a new answer literal
            s.add(implies(qi, F.arg(i)));
            qs.push_back(qi);
        }
    }
    // The solver s already contains p1 => F
    // To disable F, we add (not p1) as an additional assumption
    qs.push_back(!p1);
    std::cout << s.check(qs.size(), &qs[0]) << "\n";
    expr_vector core2 = s.unsat_core();
    std::cout << core2 << "\n";
    std::cout << "size: " << core2.size() << "\n";
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < core2.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << core2[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing with C API? Can you link me to an example? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the C++ API is just a thin layer on top of the C API. It is essentially making the C API more convenient to use.